# How to avoid the clogging the preview data output?

Tags: jquery

The editable div has the complete design of the structure of the editor adapted to the functions of the buttons that allows me to add, bold, italic, to the text written in the editable div.

Everything I write in the editable div, passes the same value to a textarea, which will allow me then to be able to insert that information into the database.

This whole process is working wonderfully.

The problem is that the data I receive in the textarea in the div of the preview is not displayed at the same time, I have to write something in the textarea to show the data in the preview.

This is my code jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
    });
    $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){                  
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
        $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    })
});
```

How do I solve this obstruction of data output in the preview?

http://jsfiddle.net/rpvthc4u/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add editor content to preview also (On key Up). See below code

```
$(function() {
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
    htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());
        $(".editor-preview").html(htmlDiv.html()); //assign content to preview
    });
    $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html());

    $('.editor-preview').keyup(function(){                  
        var value = $(this).val();
        var contentAttr = $(this).attr( 'class' );
        $( '.' + contentAttr + '' ).html(value);
    })
});
```